# Column forces its children's height to be max and I cant center a widget vertically because of that. How do i change it?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I have a column in which there is textField in the bottom and a Expanded widget taking up the rest of the vertical space above. I want to center a widget inside  this expanded that has its own size determined by that widgets children. Now when I try to run this by putting it inside a Center widget, it only centers it horizontally and makes it take up all the vertical space in the expanded. How do I solve this?

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          height: double.maxFinite,
          child: Center(
              child: TaskWidget(),
          ),
        )
    ),
    SizedBox( /* The text field */)
  ],
),
```

It seemed that every child of the column was inheriting something that forced the children take up all vertical space and it only centered when I added a column and other expanded widgets to take up that extra vertical space so that it can finally center itself.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          height: double.maxFinite,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Container()),
              TaskWidget(),
              Expanded(child: Container())
            ],
          ),
        )
    ),
    SizedBox( /* The text field */)
  ],
),
```

but I feel like this is a very incomplete solution. How can I do something that the column doesnt force the children to take up all vertical space? is there some widget I can use that doesnt pass down this to its children?
thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The [`mainAxisSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex/mainAxisSize.html) property of a `Column` defaults to `MainAxisSize.max`, set it to `MainAxisSize.min`.

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  // ...
)
```

Comment: the parent of the column already has a predetermined height so the column fills that, setting min doesnt change anything in this case I already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the SizedBox for centering:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: TaskWidget(),
    )),
    SizedBox(
      child: Text('abc'),
    )
  ],
)
```

If above does not work for you somehow, try this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TaskWidget(),
        ],
    )),
    SizedBox(
      child: Text('abc'),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: the above doesnt work and the second one is very similar to the solution in my post which is currently working (putting it in another column). But my concern is, is this best practice? is there any way in the documentation that I should read or something that I am not aware of.